# How to update the background notification with an image

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, location, android-notifications

I am trying to replicate the Uber style of updating the background notification as in the image.

[image]

I am using [Location plugin's](https://pub.dev/packages/location) `updateBackgroundNotification` method on listening the location update. However `updateBackgroundNotification` does not support image.

```
_locationSubscription = onLocationChanged(inBackground: true)
        .listen((LocationData currentLocation) async {
     
      await updateBackgroundNotification(
        subtitle:
            'Location: ${currentLocation.latitude}, ${currentLocation.longitude}',
        onTapBringToFront: true,
      );
}
```

Is there any alternative way to add an image here? I need to update the image in the same message.

Thank you.

Comment: Filing a feature request on the plugin would be good.

Comment: @Yrll, thank you. I already did that. Any idea, how this can be done with a workaround.

Comment: You're welcome! As of now, I don't know any workaround for this. I'm not sure if it's relevant or would be much of help but have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601900/flutter-image-notification